# How to remove second occuring space in handphone number using sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-formatting, phone-number

For example my handphone number is 123 456 789 i need output as 123 456789. 
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logical approach here is to split the string into two sections using [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) and [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql), up to the first space, and after the first space, then [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) the string after the first space, then use [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql) to put the string back together. e.g.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(15) = '123 456 789';

SELECT  BeforeSpace = SUBSTRING(@s, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @s)),
        AfterSpace = SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX(' ', @s), LEN(@s)),
        ReplaceAfterSpace = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX(' ', @s), LEN(@s)), ' ', ''),
        Result = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@s, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @s)),
                        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX(' ', @s), LEN(@s)), ' ', ''));
```

However, it is actually simpler, to remove all spaces using [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) and re-insert a space where the first one was originally using [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql):

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(15) = '123 456 789';

SELECT  STUFF(REPLACE(@s, ' ', ''), CHARINDEX(' ', @s), 0, ' ');
```

All that is left to do then is check for cases where there is no space. Full example:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (s VARCHAR(15));
INSERT @T VALUES ('123 456 789'), ('123456789'), ('123456 789'), ('123 4 5 6 789');

SELECT  Original = s,
        Method1 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', s) = 0 THEN s
                        ELSE CONCAT(SUBSTRING(s, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', s)), 
                                REPLACE(SUBSTRING(s, CHARINDEX(' ', s), LEN(s)), ' ', ''))
                    END,
        Method2 = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', s) = 0 THEN s
                        ELSE STUFF(REPLACE(s, ' ', ''), CHARINDEX(' ', S), 0, ' ')
                    END
FROM    @T;
```

**Output**

```
Original        Method1         Method2
-------------------------------------------
123 456 789     123 456789      123 456789
123456789       123456789       123456789
123456 789      123456 789      123456 789
123 4 5 6 789   123 456789      123 456789
```

*N.B I have made an assumption that when you say you want to replace the 2nd space, that you want to replace all spaces apart from the first. If my assumption is wrong, and it is only the 2nd space you want to replace then this won't work.*

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
DECLARE @number AS NVARCHAR(12);
SELECT @number = '123 456 789';

SELECT STUFF(@number, CHARINDEX(' ', @number, CHARINDEX(' ', @number) + 1), 1, '')  AS REMOVED_SECOND_SPACE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(12) = '111 222 333'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, 0, LEN(@s) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@s)) + 1)
     + SUBSTRING(@s, LEN(@s) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@s)) + 2, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in addition to other answers, I'll post the simpliest, based on assumption, that you want to have three digits followed by space, then the rest:

```
declare @x1 varchar(15), @x2 varchar(15), @x3 varchar(15), @x4 varchar(15), @x5 varchar(15)
set @x1 = '123456789'
set @x2 = '123 456789'
set @x3 = '123 456 789'
set @x4 = '123456 789'
set @x5 = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'

select stuff(replace(@x1, ' ', ''), 4, 0, ' ')
select stuff(replace(@x2, ' ', ''), 4, 0, ' ')
select stuff(replace(@x3, ' ', ''), 4, 0, ' ')
select stuff(replace(@x4, ' ', ''), 4, 0, ' ')
select stuff(replace(@x5, ' ', ''), 4, 0, ' ')
```

All outputs will be the same: `123 456789`.